# In what order does execution on WHERE and ON clauses work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was reading this page about APPLY:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/07/07/using-cross-apply-to-optimize-joins-on-between-conditions.aspx

And I read this article about Logical Query Processing:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/

So I can understand how this query takes a long time.

```
SELECT s.StartedAt, s.EndedAt, c.AirTime 
FROM dbo.Commercials s JOIN dbo.Calls c  
  ON c.AirTime >= s.StartedAt AND c.AirTime < s.EndedAt 
WHERE c.AirTime BETWEEN '20080701' AND '20080701 03:00'
```

The join goes through all the rows, **then** the WHERE clauses filters the results.

But why is this query lightning fast?

```
SELECT s.StartedAt, s.EndedAt, c.AirTime 
FROM dbo.Commercials s JOIN dbo.Calls c  
  ON c.AirTime >= s.StartedAt AND c.AirTime < s.EndedAt 
WHERE c.AirTime BETWEEN '20080701' AND '20080701 03:00' 
AND s.StartedAt BETWEEN '20080630 23:45' AND '20080701 03:00'
```

I get that the WHERE clauses are filtering the results of both tables. But that filtering happens **after** the JOIN, not *before* it. Now if it somehow, actually happens before the JOIN, then I definitely understand why it's so fast. But, if I go by the LOE in second link, this shouldn't be the case. Right?

Comment: Can we se the table structure? Most likley the indexes are optimal if a query is very fast. Smaller set. hard to determine without the table definition.

Comment: You would need to look at the explains to see what the optimizer is doing.  Since your join is an inner join, the optimizer may well be re-writing your query.

Comment: You checked the execution plan? You should take a look at article about sql server enginer and optimizer. I think it will always try to execute first index_seek then table_scan so as i understand, if you are running a where clause base on index and join clause based on non indexed column, it will first execute the where clause. Hmm reading again your query, i would say the optimizer did a good job, you don't have equality but > and < so it first reduces 2 temp table then joined them comparing values. It seems correct for me

Comment: The table structures and queries come from the first link.

Comment: Do you understand that "Logical" means that the system is free to perform tasks in some *other* actual/physical order, provided the results are "as if" it *had* executed them in the logical order.

Comment: **logical** query processing does not mean this is what happens in practice. If you look at the [proper documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) notice the phrase "Note that the actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list."

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive "before" and "after" on these queries. RDBMS is allowed to decide when to run what part of the query, as long as the results the query produces do not change.

In the first case, there is nothing the query can do to pre-filter the rows of `Commercials`, because the `WHERE` clause constrains only the rows of the `Calls`. These constraints specified a range for `c.AirTime` in terms of the corresponding row of `Commercials`, so no pre-filtering is possible: all rows of `Calls` would be considered for each row of `Commercials`.

In the second case, however, RDBMS can improve on the time by observing that you additionally constraint the range for `c.AirTime` to between 23:45 on Jun-30, 2008 through midnight of Jul-1, 2008 by constraining `s.StartedAt` to which `c.AirTime` is joined. This can allow the optimizer use an index, if one is defined on the `Calls.AirTime` column.

The important observation here is that the RDBMS can do very clever things when optimizing your query. It arrives at the optimized strategy by applying multiple rules of logic, trying to push the constraints closer to the "source of rows" in a join. The best option to checking what the optimizer does is reading the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

A massive amount of logic, time, blood, sweat, and tears have gone into the SQL Server Engine Optimizer, which is what determines the query plan that determines how a statement is actually processed. What is written in a statement in no way reflects what actually executes in the engine.

To really see what's going on, run your queries with the show actual query plan option enabled. My guess is that based on the additional where clause the data is being pre-filtered by the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same queries so why would you expect the same response times

If the two queries are returning a different number of rows then use a top X for a more fair comparison

Query optimizer can get very smart (and it can get stupid)
View the query plan to see what is going on

My experience is the query optimize has a better chance of getting smart if you pull the conditions into the join

```
SELECT s.StartedAt, s.EndedAt, c.AirTime 
 FROM dbo.Commercials s 
 JOIN dbo.Calls c  
   ON c.AirTime >= s.StartedAt 
  AND c.AirTime < s.EndedAt 
  AND c.AirTime BETWEEN '20080701' AND '20080701 03:00' 
  AND s.StartedAt BETWEEN '20080630 23:45' AND '20080701 03:00'
```

If you just have a single join then the query optimizer may move a where early
But if you have multiple joins I have never seen the query optimizer move a where early

Answer (score 0):

The second query is faster why you are limiting the scope of the join.

First query: A join B

Second query: A join subset(B)

As subset(B) < B itself there are a lot less matches to scan for.

And that leads to the question: the column used in that join got a index? (Probably not or the speeds cannot differ a lot)