# How does the TOP, DESC and CROSS APPLY make this query faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cross-apply

Related to this question: [In what order does execution on WHERE and ON clauses work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20522089/428757)

I was reading this page about APPLY:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/07/07/using-cross-apply-to-optimize-joins-on-between-conditions.aspx

And I don't understand how the CROSS APPLY, TOP, and DESC are making this query faster.

Original query:

```
 SELECT s.StartedAt, s.EndedAt, c.AirTime 
FROM dbo.Commercials s JOIN dbo.Calls c  
  ON c.AirTime >= s.StartedAt AND c.AirTime < s.EndedAt 
WHERE c.AirTime BETWEEN '20080701' AND '20080701 03:00'
```

Faster query:

```
SELECT s.StartedAt, s.EndedAt, c.AirTime 
FROM dbo.Calls c CROSS APPLY( 
  SELECT TOP 1 s.StartedAt, s.EndedAt FROM dbo.Commercials s  
  WHERE c.AirTime >= s.StartedAt AND c.AirTime < s.EndedAt 
  ORDER BY s.StartedAt DESC) AS s 
WHERE c.AirTime BETWEEN '20080701' AND '20080701 03:00'
```

I don't know what specific question to ask, because I don't get it.

Comment: Same post as some minutes ago, and same answer. Optimizer evaluated some plans and picked the faster one. And still for me, a cross apply on a select top 1 make sense to be faster.

Comment: I cannot see how this question is different than your previous one. I therefore marked it as duplicate.

Comment: To distill the answer into one sentence: the optimizer was forced to pick a loop join which it erroneously did not pick before. The query happens to be faster now, by coincidence.

Comment: Not the same queries. Do you get the same results? Second time you have asked why different queries have different response times.  I get you don't get it but start with comparing queries that return the same results and look at the query plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second query is likely faster because you are limiting the result set to join against to a maximum of 1 row; the first row.  There is little to no computation or join matching required for that.  In this case, your `CROSS APPLY` is acting like a singular function.